# Renaming a file in Explorer Win10 does not change modified date

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, rename, file-attributes

This is something that never occurred to me but I noticed that when I rename a file its modified attribute will remains unchanged. This happens on multiple devices I tested it on (Win10, NTFS) and for folders the same is true. However, when I modify an attribute (details tab of file properties) it updates the modified date.

Is this standard behavior? This occurred to me while using xcopy /d which did not copy seemingly newer (renamed files) from source to destination.

Thanks.

Comment: Just changing the file name (and no other attribute or manual attribute changes) does not change the date of the file. That is normal Windows behavior and has been like that for a long while.

Comment: Depending on what attributes you change those are written to the file while the filename is not a part of the file data but rather a property of the filesystem.

Comment: Why would it? Renaming a file doesn't change when it was modified. Moving a file doesn't change its creation date, why would it? Copying a file does change the creation date because its new, but not its modification date. WINDOWS SUITS HUMANS but not teenagers.

Comment: Occasionally in Windows 7, changing the name of a file would change the modified time of the file too. I think this was due to a minor bug in DropBox. It was intermittent - renamed 4 files, 2 had a new modified time.